# Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices such that $AB = 0$. Show that if $A$ is invertible, then $B = 0$.

Tags: matrices

I'm not sure how to approach this one except for the brute force approach. 
I'm sure there is a behaviour or property of matrices here that can give me the answer more elegantly though.

It seems to me that for $B$ to be not the $0$ matrix, and for $AB =0$, then we would have to have at least zeros in a row of $A$ and zeros in a column of $B$.
For example:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

This example demonstrates that if this were true, then $A$ could not be invertible because the $det(A) = 0$

But of course, this is just one example, and I'm not sure if I'm demonstrating some rule or known property that is peculiar to all matrices that are multiplied to equal $0$ or there are variations that would not require such a set up as above. 
Does anyone have any input to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just multiply $A^{-1}$ from the left and you will get the desired result.

Comment: Ok, so that would satisfy the question in the book, which I have asked in the subject of this thread. So I'm taking it that a property of invertible matrices is that they cannot multiply another matrix and = 0 without that other matrix actually being 0. Is that how it is understood? I did not know this rule.

Comment: See it's just simply coming from the fact that $A.A^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ and $B.0=0$. Where $I$ is the identity matrix and $0$ is the zero matrix. B is any matrix, might not be invertible. Also $I.B=B$.

Comment: Thanks for help @Riju